# Configuring HttpClient/HttpMessageHandler from config file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, httpclient

My *appsettings.json* file contains the following section.

```
"TrackAndTrace": {
  "DebugBaseUrl": "https://localhost:44360/api",
  "BaseUrl": "https://example.com/api",
  "Username": "Username",
  "Password": "Password",
  "CompanyCode": "CODE"
},
```

And then I'm configuring `HttpClient` as follows:

```
services.AddHttpClient<TestApi>()
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler()
        {
           // I want to incorporate this somehow:
           // services.Configure<TrackAndTraceSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("TrackAndTrace"))
           Credentials = new NetworkCredential(????, ???),
        };
    });
```

My question is: How can I get the *Username* and *Password* from the configuration file here, and assign it to `HttpClientHandler.Credentials`?

Ideally, it could be done in an efficient way such that it only needs to read from the settings file once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
var credentials = Configuration.GetSection("TrackAndTrace").Get<TrackAndTrace>();
```

TrackAndTrace model should be like this;

```
public class TrackAndTrace{
    public string DebugBaseUrl {get;set;}
    public string BaseUrl {get;set;}
    public string Username {get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}
    public string CompanyCode {get;set;}
}
```

And then you have to configure services;

```
var credentials = Configuration.GetSection("TrackAndTrace").Get<TrackAndTrace>();
services.AddHttpClient<TestApi>()
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler()
        {
           Credentials = new NetworkCredential(credentials.Username, credentials.Password),
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [overload for `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` that accepts a callback with `IServiceProvider` parameter](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/69b5d67d9418d672609aa6e2c418a3d4ae00ad18/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L203-L220).

```cs
// assuming you've set up the configuration in ConfigureServices method:
// services.Configure<TrackAndTraceSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("TrackAndTrace"))

services.AddHttpClient<TestApi>()
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler((serviceProvider) =>
    {
        var config = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<TrackAndTraceSettings>>().Value;
        return new HttpClientHandler()
        {
           Credentials = new NetworkCredential(config.Username, config.Password),
        };
    });
```